# Single phase transformer

Tags: transformer, polarity

What is the difference between additive and subtractive polarity of transformers ? Why are     they different     in different transformers ?

Comment: Can you post a diagram for _aditive_ and _substractive_ ?

Comment: Huh?  What does "additive" and "subtractive" mean relative to transformers?  Closing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ...may be vector!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a transformer with a 12 volt and a 3 volt secondary. If you connect the 3 volt secondary in series with the 12 volt volt secondary in one direction, you'll measure 15 volts across the unconnected ends. Then, if you reverse the polarity of the 3 volt winding  by connecting it, in reverse, to the same end of the 12 volt secondary, you'll read 9 volts across the unconnected ends, like this:

[image]

And here's the LTspice circuit list:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 852
WIRE -464 224 -608 224
WIRE 144 224 0 224
WIRE -608 272 -608 224
WIRE 0 272 0 224
WIRE -720 288 -944 288
WIRE -112 288 -336 288
WIRE -944 336 -944 288
WIRE -720 336 -720 288
WIRE -464 336 -464 224
WIRE -336 336 -336 288
WIRE -112 336 -112 288
WIRE 144 336 144 224
WIRE -608 400 -608 352
WIRE 0 400 0 352
WIRE -944 464 -944 416
WIRE -720 464 -720 416
WIRE -720 464 -944 464
WIRE -336 464 -336 416
WIRE -112 464 -112 416
WIRE -112 464 -336 464
WIRE -672 480 -672 272
WIRE -656 480 -656 272
WIRE -64 480 -64 272
WIRE -48 480 -48 272
WIRE -944 528 -944 464
WIRE -720 528 -720 464
WIRE -704 528 -720 528
WIRE -608 528 -608 480
WIRE -608 528 -624 528
WIRE -464 528 -464 416
WIRE -464 528 -608 528
WIRE -336 528 -336 464
WIRE -112 528 -112 464
WIRE -96 528 -112 528
WIRE 0 528 0 480
WIRE 0 528 -16 528
WIRE 144 528 144 416
WIRE 144 528 0 528
FLAG -944 528 0
FLAG -336 528 0
SYMBOL ind2 -736 320 R0
WINDOW 0 -43 40 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -43 75 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 50
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=,1
SYMBOL voltage -944 320 R0
WINDOW 3 24 104 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 339 50)
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL ind2 -592 256 M0
WINDOW 0 -46 46 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -62 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value .06
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 -592 384 M0
WINDOW 0 -46 46 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -62 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value .0039
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 -128 320 R0
WINDOW 0 -43 40 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -43 75 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L4
SYMATTR Value 50
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=,1
SYMBOL ind2 16 256 M0
WINDOW 0 -46 46 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -62 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L5
SYMATTR Value .06
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 16 496 R180
WINDOW 0 -44 82 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -55 44 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L6
SYMATTR Value .0039
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL voltage -336 320 R0
WINDOW 3 24 104 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 339 50)
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL res -480 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res 128 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res -608 512 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1G
SYMBOL res 0 512 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1G
TEXT -776 232 Left 2 !K1 L1 L2 L3  1
TEXT -176 240 Left 2 !K2 L4 L5 L6  1
TEXT -938 500 Left 2 !.tran .1
```